# IntelliJ stuck after running npm scripts

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a Scala, Play project. I am trying to add Angular2 in it. I added two npm commands through edit configuration. They are suppose to install the required packages and use webpack to bundle final JS. I notice that nothing happens after 2nd script is executed (I do not know if that script is hung or there is some other issue (see pic). It seems that the 2nd npm script is stuck because on stopping the run command, I see exit code 1 - `Process finished with exit code 1`

Is there a way to find out if Intelli build/run process is still running?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the 2nd script (npm start). I had to remove `--profile --watch` flag from the webpack command. This works - `"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress"
  }`